# Reading the last message from Kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I am trying to read the last message from a Kafka topic but I cannot make it work. I tried different methods that you can find below with their errors or problems
Topic description:

```bash
$ kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic 52.5_13.4 --describe  
Topic: 52.5_13.4    TopicId: VFJtIO-UQBiktUeO5uVQ7w PartitionCount: 1   ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: segment.bytes=1073741824
    Topic: 52.5_13.4    Partition: 0    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001  Isr: 1001
```

And the topic has multiple messages that I can get via the client.

Setup:

```py
from kafka import KafkaConsumer, TopicPartition
import json

consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092', auto_offset_reset="earliest", enable_auto_commit=True, value_deserializer=lambda x: json.loads(x.decode("utf-8")), consumer_timeout_ms=600,)
topic = TopicPartition('52.5_13.4', 0)
```

Method 1

```py
consumer.subscribe('52.5_13.4')
consumer.poll()
consumer.seek_to_end()
```

Throws

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line 865, in seek_to_end
    assert partitions, 'No partitions are currently assigned'
AssertionError: No partitions are currently assigned
```

Method 2

```py
consumer.assign([topic])
consumer.poll()
consumer.seek_to_end()

last_msg = None
for msg in consumer:
  print("Inside consumer")
  last_msg = msg.value
  print("+++")
```

This prints nothing even the print command before the `msg.value` and after the timeout of the consumer, it just gets out of the `for` loop.

Method 3

```py
consumer = KafkaConsumer('52.5_13.4', bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092', enable_auto_commit=True, value_deserializer=lambda x: json.loads(x.decode("utf-8")),consumer_timeout_ms=60000,)
topic = TopicPartition('52.5_13.4', 0)

consumer.poll()
consumer.seek_to_end(topic)
for message in consumer:
    print(message)
```

Again prints nothing and after timeout gets out of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't make `seek_to_end` work but using the combination of `end_offsets` and `seek` can do the job:

```py
from kafka import KafkaConsumer, TopicPartition
import json
consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092', auto_offset_reset="earliest", enable_auto_commit=True, value_deserializer=lambda x: json.loads(x.decode("utf-8")), consumer_timeout_ms=600,)
consumer.subscribe('52.5_13.4')
partition = TopicPartition('52.5_13.4', 0)
end_offset = consumer.end_offsets([partition])
consumer.seek(partition,list(end_offset.values())[0]-1)

for m in consumer:
  print(m.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

In each method, your consumer is going to be sitting at the end of the topic or assigned partitions, waiting for a *new record*.

You need to seek_to_end, or query for the high watermark of the partitions, then `seek()` to **that position - 1**, and poll

Comment: You are wrong, I have subscribe/assign in methods 1 and 2 but the method 3 the subscription is in the consumer. Maybe you thought I didn't because I separated the repeated part (imports and consumer creation). Anyway I found the solution and posted it.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I thought those were all distinct code blocks